# Testing of EJB3.0 deployed on weblogic 10.3.5 using JUNIT

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, weblogic, jboss-arquillian

Found arquillian can do so but it can be done using some Maven dependencies.There is no much document found for its configuration with ANT , Using IVY.xml with ant build file we can use arquillian.
I have done all thing but still @EJB can not inject BD(Business Delegates).

Comment: What is the question here, "how to do the testing?"

Comment: Yes actually , I wanna do unit testing of EJB3.0 on weblogic 10.3.5 so please suggest any idea or I need configuration detail for arquillian to test EJB 3.0 on weblogic 10.3.5

Comment: Is there anything specific here in this question ? To be honest, I've read this multiple times and I dont know what you want - running Arquillian with Ivy, or EJB injection or something else? And stop asking for details when you cant provide any.

Comment: I found that with use of spring unit testing of EJB 3.0 can successfully configured details are :